# Design Pattern for real-time systems related to network connections in Java

Tags: java, networking, real-time

I'm designing real-time system server where reliability is crucial. 
Do you know any design pattern for handling exceptions of network connection. 
Is it common to write wrapper for class **DatagramSocket** or **DatagramChannel** and implement connection retry mechanism in case any occurred exception? 
Thanks in advance for any help related to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement retry mechanism. you can try Idempotent retry design pattern for this purpose. find link below.

[image: Idempotent Retry Pattern]

http://servicedesignpatterns.com/WebServiceInfrastructures/IdempotentRetry